# how to optimize google-bigquery for finding most frequent categories from big data table?

Tags: python, bigdata, google-bigquery

I'm using `google-bigquery` on Chicago crime dataset. However, I want to find out the most frequent crime type from `primary_type` column for each distinct `block`. To do so, I come up following `standardSQL`.

**Data:**

Since the Chicago crime data is rather big, there is an official website where you can preview the dataset:[crime data on Google cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/city-of-chicago-public-data/chicago-crime)

**My current standard SQL:**

```
SELECT primary_type,block, COUNT(*) as count
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT MAX(count)
  FROM (SELECT primary_type, COUNT(*) as count FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` GROUP BY primary_type, block) `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`)
```

The problem of my above query is it has an error now, and to me, this query is quite inefficient even I fixed the error. How can I fix and optimize the above query?

**How to work with regex in standard SQL:**

To count the most frequent type for each block, including both North and South, I have to deal with `regex`, for example, `033XX S WOOD ST`, I should only get `S WOOT ST`, and `033XX N WOOD ST`. I need to get `N WOOD ST` and get the count for those. How can I do that?

**desired output:**

In my desired output, For each block such as on `WOOD ST (North (N WOOD ST)` and `South(S WOOD ST))`. I want to find the most frequent crime type. In my final output, I am expecting three columns such as `block`, `primary_type`, `count`. Is there any way to get this done with `google-bigquery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  block,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(primary_type, cnt) ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    block,
    primary_type, 
    COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` 
  GROUP BY block, primary_type
)
GROUP BY block
```

> how can I get total most frequent crime type on block WOOD ST? any hack to do this?

I am not familiar with specifics of this data, but from brief glance on it  - i think you can try below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  block,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(primary_type, cnt) ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SUBSTR(block, 8) block,
    primary_type, 
    COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` 
  GROUP BY block, primary_type
)
GROUP BY block
```

Comment: could you give me few line interpretation of your queries? I want to understand your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Inner SELECT just simply calculates counts per block and category. Outer SELECT then picks ONLY top most frequent category for each block!

Comment: I just want to understand syntax of your query, why use `ARRAY_AGG()[OFFSET(0)].* FROM()` ? why you use `.*` operation here?

Comment: try to remove `.*` and you will see the difference :o)

Comment: got it, it deal with string, right? nice trick and big big plus to your help.

Comment: it is similar to when you use `SELECT * FROM table` to select out all columns from the given table - same here - it SELECTs all fields out of STRUCT. Glad it helped :o)

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the top frequent crime by block

Inner query count calculates the frequency of crime, window partitioning function calculates the rank based on descending order of crime frequency partitioned by block. outer query where clause rank =1 return only the top frequent crime. you can change outer query where clause to get top 5 frequent crime by making it rank <=5

---

```
select * from 
      (SELECT block, primary_type, count(primary_type) as crime_frquency, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY block ORDER BY count(primary_type) DESC) AS rank
       FROM  `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime` 
       group by block, primary_type)
where rank = 1
```

---

---